# Call javascript's function from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I use below code for call javascript's function from code behind but doesn't call function

```
//C#
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "close panel", "CloseFunction()", true);

//javascript
function CloseFunction() {
            alert("call");
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be true.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "close panel", "CloseFunction()", 
true);
```

**Update Link:**

[ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)

**a Boolean value indicating whether to add script tags.**

Comment: I use both true and false but doesn't call

Comment: It works for me. However, if you call via ajax, you need `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "close panel", "CloseFunction()", true);`

Answer (score 1):

Your last parameter on the C# code should be `true`, not `false`. This will add the `<script>` tag around the script, which will execute it. Otherwise, it just prints the text out to the page.

Comment: I use both true and false but doesn't call

Comment: Then you have a different problem. Try this in a simple empty page, and you'll see that based on the question you asked, @Win and I have the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do not know about other answers, I tried all but didn't worked for me.

If anyone who is not able to do with those than try this :

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "Script", "MyJavascriptFunction();", true);
```

Ref. [this suresh sir](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/08/calling-javascript-function-from.html) Link